# what solution to be put to remove a ng-If error?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

[image]

Hello Stack Overflow, I got a problem in the project we click the country card box then the button open a single country view page but there no information show. they give me error in console window   **core.js:7951 Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.**

what should do to solve this problem?

I have tried to when we click that countries card button so button show that country full data on single country view page.

Comment: Looks initially like the old "didn't import CommonModule" in the module, or the BrowserModule in the root, thing. Check your module imports.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to import CommonModule in your Module:

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [YourComponent]
  ...
})
class YourComponentModule {}
```

Comment: Go to app.module.ts file and add the above.

Comment: I have already insert

Comment: @yash19950 can you post your code of your app.module ?